# What is cutoff when calculating speed in this equation?

Tags: movement

I saw a twitter post mention the following as way to make movement frame-rate independent:

```
changeRate = 1 - exp(-2.0 * PI * cutoff / fps)
speed -= speed * changeRate
```

What is `cutoff`?  And is `fps` a constant or the actual `fps`?

As someone unfamiliar with game development, I'm probably doing all these wrong, but the equation above is the green ball:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-davinci-f7o19?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: When referring to "a twitter post" it's always useful to add a link to the said twitter post.

Comment: Also, you have access to the source code of that moving ball, why don't you just look for the answers?

Comment: Hey @Vaillancourt, here's the [link to the tweet](https://twitter.com/MrMadbrain/status/1312442996802035713).  I wasn't sure if I was allowed to link to sites like that.

Comment: The codesandbox link is code I wrote.  I don't think it's right, but there for reference.